# How to add a progress-bar to button group with CSS bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to put a button group on the same line "directly next to" a progress bar.

I tried to use a `row` template but that create a large space between them. I like to have them directly next to each other.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="...">

                <button class="btn btn-info" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </button>

                <button class=" btn btn-info" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="progress mb-0 height-30">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-warning" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Here is a fiddler with my code https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40763/

How can I make the progress look like it is part of the button group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bootstrap 3 you'll need to extend the framework with a few 'tricks' like removing the gutter from your containers.  On top of that you'll need to transition from using `<button>` to `<a>...</a>` to take advantage of `.btn-group-justified`.

Ultimately your code would look something like this:

```css
.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.button-controls .btn-group .btn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.button-controls .progress,
.button-controls .progress-bar {
  height: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters button-controls">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <a class="btn btn-info" role="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>

        <a class=" btn btn-info" role="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-warning" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to NOT use a `row` as the `btn-group` in your case has a parent of class `col-md-3` which resolves to `25%` width and the `btn-group`, consisting of just 2 buttons would definitely not take up that amount of `width`.

Here's a fork of your fiddle: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fy77du61/)

**Change:**

Got rid of the `row` and `columns` and just added `pull-left` to the `btn-group` i.e. `float: left`

Hope this helps. :)